# SQL SERVER - Query para pegar registros todos os registros duplicados com chave distinta

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso fazer uma conferência de registros de vendas que foram duplicados da seguinte maneira.
O ID_VENDA  pode ser diferente, mas os registros de ID_PRODUTO, PRECO, DATA_VENDA, QTD_PRODUTO, ID_CLIENTE precisam ser iguais para os mesmo ID_VENDAS.

Exemplo:

| ID_VENDA | ID_PRODUTO | PRECO | DATA_VENDA | QTD_PRODUTO | ID_CLIENTE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10005458 | 877 | 22,54 | 2022-05-12 | 1 | 15558 |
| 10005458 | 101 | 88,74 | 2022-05-12 | 1 | 15558 |
| 10005458 | 253 | 9,87 | 2022-05-12 | 1 | 15558 |
| 10005600 | 877 | 22,54 | 2022-05-12 | 1 | 15558 |
| 10005600 | 101 | 88,74 | 2022-05-12 | 1 | 15558 |
| 10005600 | 253 | 9,87 | 2022-05-12 | 1 | 15558 |

Quando comecei a trabalhar na empresa percebi que existiam casos assim e preciso levantar esses casos para tentar verificar caso trate de uma inconsistência.

Comment: *"**O ID_VENDA pode ser diferente**, mas os registros de ID_PRODUTO, PRECO, DATA_VENDA, QTD_PRODUTO, ID_CLIENTE precisam ser iguais para **os mesmo ID_VENDAS**"* isso ficou confutso, o ID_VENDA pode ser diferente ou o mesmo? o que quer dizer é ter todos os campos igual, sendo diferente só o ID_VENDA?

Comment: Se eu entendi ....select ID_PRODUTO, PRECO, DATA_VENDA, QTD_PRODUTO, ID_CLIENTE from tabela group by ID_PRODUTO, PRECO, DATA_VENDA, QTD_PRODUTO, ID_CLIENTE having count(distinct ID_VENDA ) > 1